# Can SharePoint user login to another system and display the information at Sharepoint?

Tags: bcs, login

We have a SP2013 on-premise farm and another self-written web application. The web application have its login member database and is written by Java.

User would like to add a login box on SharePoint homepage (or landing page). After user key in login/password to box, the page will list out some content queried from the the self-written web application.

May I know is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Have you looked into possibility of using Business Connectivity Services to get the data?

Comment: It seems BCS is querying data based on single predefined account (usually a high level account). Hence everyone will see the same set of data. Am I right?

Comment: Can I configure BCS to map 1000 users and have users key in password themselves?

Comment: I will have to confirm but I think that you can set up Secure Store Service credentials mapping for individual logins rather than to a group (what you mean, I think?) and users will get prompted for login when trying to access  external list (reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806889.aspx#SecureStoreServiceMappings)

Comment: The web application in my case is a 20 years ago site. It doesn't support integrated security. Hence I think not work this time.